# Проблема JQUERY в цикле PHP

Tags: php, jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, я вывожу статьи и комментарии к ним в цикле PHP foreach.

```
...
foreach ($result as $articles){?>
<p><?echo $articles['title'];?></p>
<p><?echo $articles['content'];?></p>
foreach ($comm as $comment){?>
 <div class = "comment_show">
  <p><? echo $comment['user'];?></p>
  <p><? echo $comment['comm_text'];?></p>
</div>
<form class = "comment_form" action = "send.php" action ="POST">
<input type ="hidden" name ="article_id" value ="<? echo $articles['id']" class = "content_id"
 <input type ="text" name ="username" class = "userlogin">
 <textarea name ="comment" class = "comm_cont">
 <input type ="button" name ="submit" class = "submit"> 
</form>

<?php
}
}
?>
```

Код script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.submit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var content_id = $('.content_id').val(); 
    var username = $('.userlogin').val();
    var message = $('.comm_cont').val();    
    var url = $('.comment-form').attr('action');

   //e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "POST",
      data: {        
        "post_id": content_id,
        "login": username,
        "comment": message,
        "submit": $(".submit").val()
      },
      cache: false,
      dataType: 'json',      
      success: function(response){  

          $('.comment_text').val('');
          $('.comment_show').append(response.username + response.login + response.comment + response.pubdate);

        }
      });
    });
  });
```

Проблема в следующем: Форма срабатывает только в 1-й выведенной статье. В остальных - не срабатывает.

Comment: Добрый день обработчик события onclick как я вижу весит на классе submit, но я не вижу генерации элементов с таким классом...

Answer (score 1):

Проблема вашего js-кода в следующем:

```
$('.content_id').val()  // и схожие селекторы
```

не знают, **какой именно** элемент с классом `.content_id` вы хотите использовать.

Но для упрощения вашего кода уже придумана функция `serialize()`, в итоге ваш код примет следующий вид:

```
// повесьте обработчик на событие "submit"
// это позволит вам обрабатывать даже те события 
// сабмита, которые инициированы нажатием кнопки Enter
$('.comment_form').on('submit', function(e) {
    // $(this) - это форма которая сабмитится
    var url = $(this).attr('action');

    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "POST",
      // $(this) - это форма которая сабмитится
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      cache: false,
      dataType: 'json',      
      success: function(response){  
          $('.comment_text').val('');
          $('.comment_show').append(response.username + response.login + response.comment + response.pubdate);
        }
    });
});
```

Каждая форма будет выглядеть так:

```
<!-- Обратите внимание что POST это method-аттрибут -->
<form class = "comment_form" action = "send.php" method ="POST">
    <input type ="hidden" name ="article_id" value ="<? echo $articles['id']?>" class = "content_id">
    <input type ="text" name ="username" class = "userlogin">
    <textarea name ="comment" class = "comm_cont">
    <input type ="button" name ="submit" class = "submit"> 
</form>
```

На сервере вы должны будете проверить массив `$_POST` на то что он не пустой, или в нем есть, например, поле `username`, так как кнопка сабмита **не передается** на сервер. Проверить, какие ключи/значения приходят на сервер в массиве `$_POST` вы можете через `print_r($_POST)`.

Comment: я пробовал вариант с serialize и вешал событие " submit", но выходила ошибка и данные не записывались в БД

Comment: Ну а 
```
$('.content_id').val()
```
передает id поста, статьи, к которым оставили комментарий, в БД

Comment: Я не могу дистанционно определить, какая ошибка выводится. У вас __не один__ `$('.content_id').val()` поэтому скрипт не знает __который из них нужно использовать__ и берет первый.

Comment: 3 статьи с id = 1, 2, 3 . В моем 1-м варианте, в БД записываются и выводятся все данные к 1-ой статье. Но во второй и третьей статье не срабатывает.

Comment: Пожалуйста, перечитайте мой ответ ещё раз, попробуйте предложенный мной код. Если не получается - задайте ещё один вопрос, не стоит разводить обсуждение в комментариях.