# Обращение к элементам форм, выводимых в цикле

Tags: javascript, php

Форма комментариев к статьям выводится в цикле php.
Как в js обратиться к каждому элементу форм?

Код формы:

```
<form class = "comment_form" action = "send.php" action ="POST">
    <input type ="hidden" name ="article_id" value ="<? echo $articles['id']?>" class = "content_id"> 
    <input type ="text" name ="username" class = "userlogin">
    <textarea name ="comment" class = "comm_cont">
    <input type ="button" name ="submit" class = "submit">
</form>
```

Форма JS

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

      $('.submit').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var content_id = $('.content_id').val(); 
        var username = $('.userlogin').val();
        var message = $('.comm_cont').val();    
        var url = $('.comment-form').attr('action');

       //e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
          url: url,
          type: "POST",
          data: {        
            "post_id": content_id,
            "login": username,
            "comment": message,
            "submit": $(".submit").val()
          },
          cache: false,
          dataType: 'json',      
          success: function(response){  

              $('.comment_text').val('');
              $('.comment_show').append(response.username + response.login + response.comment + response.pubdate);

            }
          });
        });
      });
```

Comment: Код формы выложите

Comment: ```
<form class = "comment_form" action = "send.php" action ="POST">
<input type ="hidden" name ="article_id" value ="<? echo $articles['id']" class = "content_id"
 <input type ="text" name ="username" class = "userlogin">
 <textarea name ="comment" class = "comm_cont">
 <input type ="button" name ="submit" class = "submit"> 
</form>
```

Comment: к каким именно эл-там надо обращаться? И для чего?

Comment: Ко всем. Т.к. форма выводиться вместе со статьями в цикле PHP, онклик событие в js обращается только к элементам первой формы. (Для отпраки комментария без перезагрузки)

Comment: Вы ajax'ом отправляете комментарии? Или для чего тут вообще js?

Comment: @Хруст, обратите внимание на то, что в предоставленной Вами вёрстки содержаться ошибки...не закрытые теги...первый инпут вообще оборван

Comment: Да, ajaxom отправляю.

Comment: Добавьте свою отправку ещё, на js

Comment: @ InDevX , добавил

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проблема JQUERY в цикле PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/977653/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-jquery-%d0%b2-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b5-php)

Comment: Одно и то же спрашиваете, хоть бы чуть-чуть разобрались.

Comment: @ u_mulder , пробую, не получается. Хоть начало scripta подскажите, как обратиться, пожалуйста

Comment: `var content_id = $(this).parent().find('.content_id').val();`

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Вопрос закрыт

Comment: Этот код зависит от разметки. Как  только вы измените разметку вашей формы - ваш скрипт может перестать работать. Поэтому __настоятельно__ рекомендую перейти на `serialize`, так как ему __все равно__ на разметку.